# SPARQL Query with property path not working

Tags: sparql, jena, propertypath

I want to make a query that does the following: Select all triples `(s,p,o)` if there exists a path with the length of at least 2 edges from `s` to `o` with the property `p`. So all edges of the path have to be labelled with `p`.
I tried the following:

```
select  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf> ?o
WHERE { 
?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf>{2,} ?o.
?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf> ?o 
}
```

I executed it with the Jena API:

```
ParameterizedSparqlString parameterizedSparql = new ParameterizedSparqlString(model);
parameterizedSparql.setCommandText(sparql);
Query query = QueryFactory.create(parameterizedSparql.asQuery().toString(), Syntax.syntaxARQ);
QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model).execSelect();
```

I used `Syntax.syntaxARQ` so that it should understand property paths.

It gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "{" "{ "" at line 3, column 42.
Was expecting one of:
<IRIref> ...
<PNAME_NS> ...
<PNAME_LN> ...
<BLANK_NODE_LABEL> ...
<VAR1> ...
<VAR2> ...
```

Can you please show me how I can make the query correctly?

Comment: You can't use `{2,}` - this feature never made it to the [final property path syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) and was just discussed in the [working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/). Anything beyond is implementation specific, thus, depends on the triple store.

Comment: and the obvious workaround is to use a sequence `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf>/<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf>+` which is the same as "2 or more"

Comment: Suggestion: print out and check the syntax of `parameterizedSparql.asQuery().toString()`.

Comment: `SELECT ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf> ?o` doesn't do what you probably think it does.  Instead, try `SELECT ?s  ( <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/isPartOf> AS ?p ) ?o` ... and consider a one-line graph pattern with `{1,}` instead of your two-line pattern above.

Comment: `ParameterizedSparqlString.asQuery()` isn't needed. Just use`parameterizedSparql.toString()`. `ParameterizedSparqlString.asQuery` does not work with extended syntax queries.

Comment: As noted by @AndyS not supported currently, tracked as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1705

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, as @AKSW noted, the `{2,}` syntax [from the SPARQL 1.1 Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/) didn't make it into [the final SPARQL 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths), so you can't rely on it being supported by every SPARQL processor.

You *can* [use the `{2,}` syntax with Virtuoso](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%20%3Fs%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FisPartOf%3E%20%3Fo%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fs%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FisPartOf%3E%7B2%2C%7D%20%3Fo.%0D%0A%3Fs%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FisPartOf%3E%20%3Fo%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), which is the engine powering [the public DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), but to do so through Jena, you have to either use "extended syntax" (`Syntax.syntaxARQ`) or [bypass the ARQ parser](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider#Bypass%20Jena%2FARQ%20parser).

It appears that your immediate issue comes down to a bug in Jena, where [`ParameterizedSparqlString.asQuery()` does not currently support "extended syntax" (`Syntax.syntaxARQ`) queries](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1705); `parameterizedSparql.toString()` should be sufficient, as commented by @AndyS.

Comment: The `{2,}` does work in Apache Jena when parsed as `Syntax.syntaxARQ`. You can try it at http://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html. The code above is not calling DBPedia directly - it is a local query execution.

Comment: @AndyS - I guess "SPARQL extended syntax" means "parse as `Syntax.syntaxARQ`"?  I wonder if some older version(s) of Jena would deliver the error the OP reported even with `Syntax.syntaxARQ` active, as also reported?

Comment: `{2,}` has existed for quite a while.